# iOS Application with images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, photo-gallery

I have an iOS app with a list of objects. Each object has some properties such as title, date, etc.. and one of the properties is a `UIImage`.
User can add image from gallery or take photo from camera.
How can I realize it? I don't have any ideas about it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody interesting in this question - http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/
You can add photoes from gallery or from camera

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:
http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_nd_edition_

Comment: maybe there are some video tutorials?

Comment: Yes! http://teamtreehouse.com
There are also great search engines, that you can use instead of waiting for others to do the work for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can Take Photo or Choose From Library.

https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake

Comment: You posted links to your project five times in a short period of time, and either were not answering the question or failed to disclose your authorship of the project. Note that self-promotion can be a touchy subject here; Stack Overflow isn't really here for you to promote your project in this way.

Comment: I understand that you want to have people use your open source library, but don't just post a link to it across many questions. You need to craft answers that provide at least a little explanation of what it is and how it can address the specific problem at hand. Several of your answers had nothing to do with what was being asked, so I had to remove those. The community responds poorly to anything that even remotely resembles spam, so you'll want to be careful in your promotion of this project.

Comment: I thought having a username in the URL was clear, but I'll be more explicit in the future to avoid confusion. This project (more like a snippet) is a long winded response to a question originally from SO, I'll keep it relevant and informative when posting. Thanks for the heads up.